# 'ProjectFormFormSet' object has no attribute 'request'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I want to add to my project one feature that only authenticated users can have access their stuff. But when I write queryset it throws an error like `ModelNameFormSet object has no request attribute`

**views.py**

```
class BaseAuthorFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.queryset = Project.objects.filter(author_id=self.request.user.pk)


def add_object(request):
  ProjectFormSet = modelformset_factory(Project, formset=BaseAuthorFormSet, fields=( 'service_name', 'service_code', 'report_month', 'report_year', 'last_year'), extra=1)
  if request.method == "POST":
    form = ProjectFormSet(request.POST)
    form.author = request.user
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
form = ProjectFormSet()
return render(request, 'app1/home.html',{'form':form})
```

I have only this code. How can I solve this issue? Thank you beforehand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the request in the formset, you need to pass it there. Also note that adding the author to the formset won't do anything, you need to add it to the result of each form save.

```
class BaseAuthorFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request')
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.queryset = Project.objects.filter(author_id=self.request.user.pk)


def add_object(request):
  ProjectFormSet = modelformset_factory(Project, formset=BaseAuthorFormSet, fields=( 'service_name', 'service_code', 'report_month', 'report_year', 'last_year'), extra=1)
  if request.method == "POST":
    formset = ProjectFormSet(request.POST, request=request)
    if formset.is_valid():
        for form in formset:
          obj=form.save(commit=False)
          obj.author = request.user
          obj.save()
          return redirect('somewhere')
  form = ProjectFormSet(request=request)
  return render(request, 'app1/home.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel it works but please can you explain that self.request = kwargs.pop('request') why is it necessary?

Comment: Which bit of that don't you understand?

Comment: self.request = kwargs.pop('request')

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure what about it you don't understand.